# HTML Agility Pack get all anchors' href attributes on page

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to add links extracted from an HTML file to a `CheckBoxList` (`cbl_items`).

It works so far but instead of the link, the item's name is displayed as HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.
I tried using `DocumentElement` instead of `Node` but it said that it does not exist or similar.

How can I get the URL to be displayed instead of HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc = hw.Load(tb_url.Text);
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
  cbl_items.Items.Add(link);
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are adding the `HtmlNode` *object* to the `CheckBoxList` and not the value of the `href` attribute. What you are seeing is the `HtmlNode`'s `ToString()` value since that's the best that the `CheckBoxList` can do to display that object.

Instead, you can use `GetAttributeValue(string attribute, string defaultValue)` to retrieve the `href` attribute's value.

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc = hw.Load(tb_url.Text);
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    // Get the value of the HREF attribute
    string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue( "href", string.Empty );
    cbl_items.Items.Add(hrefValue);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to allow for the fact that `SelectNodes` (mind-bogglingly) returns `null` if no nodes match.

Comment: There is now HtmlDocument.OptionEmptyCollection, when set to true, SelectNodes will return an empty collection instead of null.