# C# Web Crawler and NoSQL Database

Tags: c#, database, nosql

I'm an IT student and we need to develop a C# program that gets all the information from a website and then use NoSQL to add the information to an Oracle database. I've got a few questions and would really appreciate some help.

We decided to use the Autotrader (http://www.autotrader.co.za/) website and
MongoDB for NoSQL.

So far I'm using the following code to write information from the website to a text file, but the problem is that it only gets information from the current page, and not the entire website.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
resp.Close();
return sourceCode;
```

I would like to know how I can follow all the links and get all the information from the website (not just the current page), without going to any other websites.

Secondly, after I have all information from the website, how should I go about retrieving specific information for the Oracle database with MongoDB etc.

Comment: "C# Web Crawler and NoSQL Database" is not a question. Read [ask]

Comment: this should be asked in two separate questions.

Comment: you might want to take a look at my implementation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16975398/1610747

Answer (score 0):

I can help with the first part of your question. You can use `HtmlAgilityPack` to find all the links in the web page you just **scraped** .
you can read about how you can use do it from this question [HTML Agility Pack get all anchors' href attributes on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688847/html-agility-pack-get-all-urls-on-page).

basically what you need to do is Initialize an `HttpDocument` from the response stream then do.

```
   var nodes =
            _htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
        if(nodes != null)
           var links = nodes.Select(a => a.Attributes["href"])
                         .Select(a => a.Value).Distinct();
```

Once you have your list of URLs, you can recursivly call the **scraper** function for each of the urls.

Here is more information about HtmlAgilityPack. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659019/Scraping-HTML-DOM-elements-using-HtmlAgilityPack-H

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Yohannes, I'll start working an that for now.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an existing Web Automation library such as Selenium WebDriver (a good example here http://seleniumdotnet.blogspot.co.uk/) to drive the web page - these allow you to query and drive the web page like a user would.